# How to deal with interaction between several dummy variables and one continuous variables in one or two regression models?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interaction

I want to know the relationship between revenue and cost in several conditions.

Dependent variables is REVENUE.REVENUE is a continuous variable from 0~1000+.I have several key independent variables: COST, LEVEL1~LEVEL4 and RESPONSE.

COST is continuous variable from 0~1000+. Level1~LEVE4 are dummy variables;LEVEL1=1 means the customer-firm relationship is weak, and LEVEL4=1 means a customer-firm relationship is strongest. RESPONSE is dummy variable; it means that a customer responds to promotion activities in a given month.

My current model is as following.

**REVENUE=β0+β1COST+β2LEV1+β3LEV2+β4LEV3+β5LEV4+β6LEV1*COST +β7LEV2 *COST+β8LEV3*COST+β9LEV4*COST**

I want to add RESPONSE into the model. I think it will be too complex, if I add one more dummy variable into the model.

Should I change LEVEL1~LEVEL4 to a ordinary variable (NEW_LEVEL=1~4), and put the dummy variable, RESPONSE, into the model?
**REVENUE=β0+β1COST+β2NEW_LEVEL+β3RESPONSE+β4NEW_LEVEL * COST+β5 NEW_LEVEL * RESPONSE+β6COST* NEW_LEVEL* RESPONSE**

Should I just use RESPONSE to separate the one data set into two data sets and run the model separately? But I do not know how to compare the coefficients in two models.
**Group_1:RESPONSE**
REVENUE=β0+β1COST+β2LEV1+β3LEV2+β4LEV3+β5LEV4+β6LEV1*COST +β7LEV2*COST+β8LEV3*COST+β9LEV4*COST

**Group_2:No_RESPONSE**
REVENUE=β0+β1COST+β2LEV1+β3LEV2+β4LEV3+β5LEV4+β6LEV1*COST +β7LEV2*COST+β8LEV3*COST+β9LEV4*COST

Thanks in advance.